# How to use an Express Error middleware for my case?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-promise

I'm using a router middleware to check if the request is valid or not.  Also, I'm using a global Error handler middleware at the end of the server.js to catch and process all the errors.

Inside the router, I'm facing a problem implementing this. The following code will state the problem clearly.

Error middleware errorHandler.js

```
module.exports = function(err, req, res, next) {
    //some logic
    return res.status(400 or 500).json({err});
};
```

My server.js (short version)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/account/:accid/users', userRouteHandler);

const errorHandler = require('PATH to errorHandler.js file');
app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 3000!`));
```

userRouteHandler file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
router.use(express.json());

// middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {

  /**** PROBLEM / CONFUSION ****/

  checkIfAccountIdExists(req.params.accid) //if exists resolve(count) else reject(new Error)
    .then(next)   //I want to allow calling the get if it exists
    .catch(next); //for error it should call the global error handler
});

router
  .get('/', function(req,res,next){
    console.log("entering here"); 
    findAllTheUsers({accid:req.params.accid})
      .then(users=>res.status(200).json(users);
      .catch(err=>next(err)); //ensure it can call the global error handler
  });
```

The code always calling the get route. As for both, I'm calling next(). If I call next() only inside then(), my global error handler will get skipped if any error occurs.

One way could be directly calling my errorHanler function within the catch block. but I want to keep my code separate and don't really want to require my errorHandler file within each route.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the behavior of your `checkIfAccountIdExists` function, my supposition is that it returns a promise that always resolves with `false|undefined|null`; something like this:

```
checkIfAccountIdExists(id).then((exists) => console.log(exists));
// outputs "false" or "undefined" or "null"
```

It's my supposition, because otherwise your `.get('/')` route shouldn't even enter, given how `next()` works.

#### Understanding `next()`:

Calling `next()` *(to the shame of Express)* has always been confusing without having in-depth knowledge of it. It basically works in 3 ways:

- **`next()`** (no arguments) -> pass execution to next callbacks in the
  route
- **`next('route')`** (the string `'route'` argument) -> bypass any remaining callbacks in the route (moves into any routes that follow)
- **`next(err)`** (any other truthy parameters, aside from `'route'`) -> invokes the error handlers.

In your specific case, my assumption is that `checkIfAccountIdExists()` solves with `false|undefined|null`, essentially invoking `next(err)` signature, but because `err` is not truthy, it's treated as a `next()` signature, moving onto the next route callback. I'd check the sanity of `checkIfAccountIdExists()` for this.

### Using `next()` with Promises

When using Promises, it's important to remember that your first argument of `.then()` (meaning your *fulfillment* handler) **will always receive a parameter**!

```
promise.then(callback);

function callback() {
  console.log(arguments.length); // ALWAYS 1
}
```

For this reason, you should always avoid setting `next()` as a fulfillment handler to promises. Otherwise, once your `checkIfAccountIdExists()` will solve with `true`, it will actually invoke the `next(err)` signature!

Always write: `promise.then(() => next())` instead of `promise.then(next)`, to make sure you call `next` without arguments.

Writing `promise.catch(next)` is however fine, because it's the same as `promise.catch((err) => next(err))`

#### A bit more info on Promises

Also, Promises (`thenables`) allow for two arguments on `.then()`, one being a fulfillment handler and one a rejection handler.
Example: `promise.then(onFulfillment, onRejection)` which is similar to calling `promise.then(onFulfillment).catch(onRejection)` **except** of how errors are caught!

- For `.then(onFulfillment, onRejection)` any errors that are thrown
  inside `onFulfillment` are never caught by `onRejection`.
- For `.then(onFulfillment).catch(onRejection)` any errors that are thrown
  inside `onFulfillment` are also caught by `onRejection`

In your case, that means you can safely write

```
checkIfAccountIdExists.then(() => next(), next);
```

because the next route *(onFulfillment arg)* will also handle errors.
*Note: errors inside synchronous code will be caught by express.*

More info:

- [Express Error Handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)
- [Promise.prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: checkIfAccountIdExists(id) function return a Promise that got resolved(count) if the id exists and reject(Error instance). If the id does not exist it will pass a custom Error object or else Mongoose error object. So my next(error) was always getting called. What I didn't know that next is overloaded and any truthy argument calls the error handler directly.
Thank you for your explanation! :)

Comment: Actually, I solved this this alternative method, could you please tell me if its a good or bad practice?
`app.use('/account/:accid/users', function(req,res,next) {
 return db.Org().isExists({ accid: req.params.accid })
  .then(function(){ return userRouteHandler(req,res,next); })
  .catch(next);
});`
This working fine for my case.